# Missing Required Positional Argument

Tags: python, typeerror, positional-argument

In my program, I am trying to find if a certain variable is in a list. However, I keep getting the following error and I am very stuck on how to get past it:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\My Drive\DGT301\Python\AS\order.py", line 171, in confirm_order
    self.check(self.order_item, self.food_list)
TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here is  my code:

```
def find(thing, list3d):
    for x in list3d:
         for y in x:
            if y[1] == thing:
                return True
    return False

def check(item, list3d, result, self):
    self.result = 'found' if self.find(item, list3d) else 'not found'
    print(f'{item} was {result}')

def confirm_order(self):
    self.order_item = self.r.get()
    self.check(self.order_item, self.food_list)
```

I tried putting "self." before all the variables and tried removing some and the error stays the same.

Comment: Is that all your code? Methods belonging to a class will need `self` as the first arg. What you posted are just orphaned methods without context.

Comment: You don't need to use `self.` as I believe all your variables are within the function's scopes / passed as parameters, and you don't need it on the functions as all your functions are in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a method on an object, the Python interpreter will automatically insert a reference to that object as the first positional argument. To handle this, the first argument for a method (a function defined inside a class) conventionally calls the first argument `self`. Your functions are not defined inside of a class, so the use of `self` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers, you have also added `self` to the end of the parameter list for check() which is the specific cause of the error. Your function is expecting four parameters `def check(item, list3d, result, self)` but the function calling it is only passing two: `self.check(self.order_item, self.food_list)`

...actually, why is the error code only reporting 1 missing parameter instead of 2? `result` should be missing as well? Maybe there's some python magic there I don't understand...

```
def check(item, list3d, result, self):

    # four parameters expected by the function ^^^

    self.result = 'found' if self.find(item, list3d) else 'not found'
    print(f'{item} was {result}')

def confirm_order(self):
    self.order_item = self.r.get()
    self.check(self.order_item, self.food_list)

    # Only two parameters being sent to the function ^^^
```

If these functions are actually part of a class, then you will need to put it as the first parameter in each function within the class, but basically ignore it when calling the function.

For example:

```
def check(self,item,list3d,result):
    #etc., etc.

def confirm_order(self):
    self.check(item,list3d,result)
```